# Add condition to arrow function

Tags: javascript

I have the below code snippet,

```
  {categoriesWithSub.length > 0 &&
     categoriesWithSub.map(item => {
    //Add new condition here
      const pageChanges = {
        catId: item.id,
        catName: item.catName,
      };
      return (
        <Tile
          to="./request"
          text={item.catName}
          key={item.id}
          onClick={() => handleChange('departments', pageChanges)}
        />
      );
    })}
```

how can I add to the below a sub condition on `item`, something like that:

```
item.subCategories.length > 0 ?
return (...): 
retrun (  
    <Tag
        text={''}
        to="../exact-request"
        key={0}
        onClick={() => handleChange('request', '')}
    />
```

I tried that but something is wrong with the syntax:

```
{categoriesWithSub.length > 0 &&
    categoriesWithSub.map(item => {
      item.subCategories.length > 0 ?(
      const pageChanges = {
        catId: item.id,
        catName: item.catName,
      };
      return (
        <Tile
          to="./request"
          text={item.catName}
          key={item.id}
          onClick={() => handleChange('departments', pageChanges)}
        />
      );
      ):
      retrun (
       <Tag
          text={''}
          to="../exact-request"
          key={0}
          onClick={() => handleChange('request', '')}
        />
      )
    })}
```

Comment: Ternaries are for expressions, `return` is not an expression. May just use an `if` instead?

Comment: `return (item.subCategories.length > 0) ? ... : ... ;` But as said, an `if` statement is the way to go here.

Comment: Ternary conditions should not be used this way. They expect an expression inside them and also they should be used only for simple conditions like `a > b ? a : b` . Although they look 'cool' i suggest you use old fashioned `if` statement

Comment: Thanks all for the comments, I'm always happy to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iam not sure I got it completly what you wanted, but you can just add the condition there. But I would say doing this in render is bad practice, in render you should render this should be a function or component.

```js
{
  categoriesWithSub.length > 0 &&
    categoriesWithSub.map(item => {
      if (item.subCategories.length > 0 ) {
        return something
      }
      return somethingElse
    })
}
```

or if you insist on using ternars

```js
{
  categoriesWithSub.length > 0 &&
    categoriesWithSub.map(item => {
      return item.subCategories.length > 0 ?
        something :
        somethingElse
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
return (item.subCategories.length > 0) ?
(...): 
(  
    <Tag
        text={''}
        to="../exact-request"
        key={0}
        onClick={() => handleChange('request', '')}
    />
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's litle strange aproach but it's simple:

```
return item.subCategories.length > 0 ?
(
    <Some ... />
) :
(
    <Tag
    text={''}
    to=../exact-request
    key={0}
    onClick={() => handleChange('request', '')}
/>
);
```

But i recomend you writing code like this:

```
if (item.subCategories.length > 0) {
    return <Some ... />
}

return (
        <Tag
        text={''}
        to=../exact-request
        key={0}
        onClick={() => handleChange('request', '')}
    />)
```

Your code must be readable

Answer (score 0):

You can return that condition in the beginning if falsey:

```
{categoriesWithSub.length > 0 &&
   categoriesWithSub.map(item => {
   const someCondition = <...>
   if (!someCondition) return false;
   // rest of your code
```